# Joomla Component jQuery datetimepicker no effect

Tags: jquery, css, joomla

I am building a joomla component. I need to add a datetimepicker into the form of the file view/tmpl/default.php, but it does not work.

I tried the include through JHtml according to the link 
http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page

But I am not sure which path to put the script and css.

Am I going to create a file named com_event which is of the same name to my component, put the file in the media folder, within it, there are the css and js file? Is that correct? But it won't work.

Or am I going to put the js and css files into the template js and css folder,

But it won't work, either.

I hope anyone would help me.

Thank you.

The code i've tried:

```
<?php 
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
$document = JFactory::getDocument();

// Add Javascript
$script = 'jQuery(\'#datetimepicker\').datetimepicker();';
$script2 = 'jQuery(\'#datetimepicker\').datetimepicker({value:\'\',step:30});';
$document->addScriptDeclaration($script);
$document->addScriptDeclaration($script2);
$document->addStyleSheet('com_event/css/jquery.datetimepicker.css');
$document->addScript('com_event/js/jquery.datetimepicker.js');
$document->addScript('com_event/js/jquery.js');


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For how you have the code written they would be put in the folders called com_event/css and com_event/js inside the top level, which is really bad form.

Joomla likes it if you put this stuff in the media folder, but you could put it in the components folder or the media folder or anywhere else as long as you put the full path to it:

Components:

```
$script = "jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();";
$script2 = "jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({value:'',step:30});";
$document->addScriptDeclaration($script);
$document->addScriptDeclaration($script2);
$document->addStyleSheet("/component/com_event/css/jquery.datetimepicker.css");
$document->addScript("/component/com_event/js/jquery.datetimepicker.js");
$document->addScript("/component/com_event/js/jquery.js");
```

Media:

```
$script = "jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();";
$script2 = "jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({value:'',step:30});";
$document->addScriptDeclaration($script);
$document->addScriptDeclaration($script2);
$document->addStyleSheet("/media/com_event/css/jquery.datetimepicker.css");
$document->addScript("/media/com_event/js/jquery.datetimepicker.js");
$document->addScript("/media/com_event/js/jquery.js");
```

If one of these folders already exists, and you are adding to a previous built component, then that would be the one to choose.

When I build a component I prefer to not use the media folder to keep this stuff, since it is a pain to have files so separated. It is your choice though.

Comment: how about $script = 'jQuery(\'#datetimepicker\').datetimepicker();'; Is it Correct? I escape the special character '.

Comment: no, you don't need to do that. Sorry I missed that part. I would use " instead of ' and don't escape any of the double quotes or single quotes. I will update my answer.

Comment: Hi, i've tried to add the script as what you said, but it still won't work. Is it because of the restrictions of the template, since some of the css of default.php won't work in the template either.

Comment: when you say it does not work, what do you mean? When you look at the source code do you see the scripts have loaded? Or is the date time picker just not working? I was under the assumption that it was just that you could not get the scripts to load.

Comment: also, what version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: You may need to wrap your javascript in a `jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();});` to get it to run if you are getting all your scripts to load.

Comment: Also, I just realized you may be trying to load this on the administrator side of things in which case you script/css paths should be /administrator/component/... if you are putting them in the component folder in order to get them to load